# JavaScript play and host download links of audio

Tags: javascript, audio, download, playback

I am very new to JavaScript. I am making a website, I have executed a query from SQL server and display results like this:

| title | file name | duration | download |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| title 1 | 001.mp3 | 09:00 | button |
| title 2 | 002.mp3 | 07:05 | button |

with code like this:

```html
<td><a class="is_online" onclick= "curr_track.play()"> {{ title }} </a></td>
<td> {{filename}} </td>                               
<td> {{duration}} </td>
<td><button class="btn_enable"><i class="fa fa-download"></i></button></td>
```

I expect that when I clicked on the title, the audio controller will appear below the current title and when I click on download, the file downloaded will be the title name not the file name.

[image: 1]

Comment: you must have some javascript to do those actions - show it

Comment: Thanks to zcoop98 and Evolutionxbox for editing the question for me.